# How can I refactor the element type of Generics in eclipse, any shortcuts?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, refactoring

I'm in trouble with refactorring the element type of generics, please check the image below,

**The type of element is "String", and now I want to refactor it to "Integer", how should I do in eclipse. I DO NOT want to change the type of "titleName" !!**. I've checked that if I select the type name and right-click, there is no "Rename" in the context menu :-(

I refactorred the type with the "help/replace" as a workaround, however, I don't think this is a good way, it may cause typos.

[image: Code refactor example]

well, I know my question is a bit little weird, but I think lots of guys may encoutered. For instance, how to change `"Map<String,Integer> map = HashMap<String, Integer>()" to "Map<Integer,User> map = HashMap<Integer, User>()"`?

Comment: replace all will cause typos, if I declared "private String titleName" as the field of InnerIterator, since I don't want to change "titleName" to Integer. And it may get worse if I have lots of local String variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
CTRL + F 
FIND: <String>
REPLACE WITH: <Integer>
Replace All
```

Comment: Hi, Robert. I dont think "replace all" is a remedy, in this case, the element type of Iterable is String, so the next() method should return String, if I simply replace it all to Integer, "public String next()" won't be changed.

Comment: My bad, just do the same thing without the '<' and '>'

Comment: Yes, it somewhat fixes the problem before, but if I declared lots of "String" varaibles which I don't want to be replaced to "Integer", this proposal may mess up the codes. It is driving me crazy, since manually replacing will cause typos :-(

Comment: well, I know my question is a bit little weird, but I think lots of guys may encoutered.  For instance, how to change "Map<String,Integer> map = HashMap<String, Integer>()" to "Map<Integer,User> map = HashMap<Integer, User>()" ?

Comment: Hi, I updated my post, still there? any suggestion, thanks in advance.